# Upload 650,000 documents to Azure

Tags: azure

I can't seem to find any reference to bulk uploading data to azure.

I have a document store with 650,000 pdf document that take up about 1.2 TB of disk space.

Uploading those files to Azure via the web will be difficult.  Is there a way I can mail a hard drive and have your team upload them for me?

If not can you recommend the best way to upload this many documents?

Comment: "Your team"?  When did stackoverflow buy out microsoft?

Comment: With a 1 gb / sec connection that is a 15 day transfer.  How fast do you need it loaded?   Not reflection on you but my experience with this type of requirement is that management will take 2 months to pull the trigger and then demand a 2 day upload.  Azure has a sales support help.

Comment: JK, ms allows for tech support on msdn forums or stack.  They say to tag the comment on stack with Azure and they will read it, so I was addressing the ms group.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the answer you expected, but you could use Amazon's **[AWS Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/)** (this allows you to mail them a HDD and they'll import it in your S3 account).

To transfer the data to a Windows Azure Storage Account you can leverage one of the new features in the 1.7.1 SDK: the **[StartCopyFromBlob](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx)** method. This method allows you to copy a file at a specific url in an asynchronous way (you could use this to copy all files from your S3 to your Azure storage account).

Read the following blogpost for a fully working example: [How to Copy a Bucket from Amazon S3 to Windows Azure Blob Storage using “Copy Blob”](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/15/how-to-copy-a-bucket-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/)

Comment: Thank you for the link to "How to copy..."

Answer (score 1):

While Azure doesn't offer a physical ingestion process today, if you talk nicely to the Azure team they can do this as a one off. If you like I can get a contact on the product team for you (dave at greenbutton dot com).

Alternatively there are solutions such as Aspera which provide for accelerated data transfers over UDP and is being beta test in Azure along with the Azure Media Services offering.

We have some tools that help with this as well http://www.greenbutton.com and leverage Aspera's technology.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your input.  I am just in the exloritory phase now.

Answer (score 1):

As disk shipment are not supported by Windows Azure, your best bet is use a 3rd party application (or write your own one) which supports parallel upload. This way you can still upload much faster. 3rd party applications like Gladinet, Cloudberry could be used for upload the data but I am not sure how configurable they are to get maximum parallel upload to achieve fastest upload.

If you decide to write by yourself here is the starting point: [Asynchronous Parallel Block Blob Transfers with Progress Change Notification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/30/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that linke on the parallel transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit too late for the OP, but in the Azure Management Portal, under Storage, pick your storage instance, then click the Import/Export link at the top. At the bottom of that screen, there is a "Create Import Job" link and icon. Also, if you click the blue help icon on the far right side, it says this:

*You can use the Windows Azure Import/Export service to transfer large amounts of file data to Windows Azure Blob storage in situations where uploading over the network is prohibitively expensive or infeasible. You can also use the Import/Export service to transfer large quantities of data resident in Blob storage to your on-premises installations in a timely and cost-effective manner. Use the Windows Azure Import/Export Service to Transfer Data to Blob Storage*

*To transfer a large set of file data into Blob storage, you can send one or more hard drives containing that data to a Microsoft data center, where your data will be uploaded to your storage account. Similarly, to export data from Blob storage, you can send empty hard drives to a Microsoft data center, where the Blob data from your storage account will be copied to your hard drives and then returned to you. Before you send in a drive that contains data, you'll encrypt the data on the drive; when Microsoft exports your data to send to you, the data will also be encrypted before shipping.*

Answer (score 0):

Both windows azure storage powershell and azcopy could bulk upload data to azure.

For azure storage powershell, you could use `ls -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container upload`.

You can refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408487.aspx for more details.

For azcopy, you can refer this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx